# Macbook Pro Mid-2015 - Rightside Fan 0rpm - Sensor Error?

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature, kernel

I have a recurring issue which is causing me problems:

My MacBook Pro mid-2015 rightside fan seems not to be working. I have used different software (Macs Fan Control, iStat) to determine this.

This causes kernel task to fill up the memory and stops me from doing the things I need to.

I previously replaced this fan and did have some success, but the issue is back.

However, when I power on with the shell open, both fans are spinning perfectly fine - so this leads me to believe a sensor is incorrectly reading the RPM of the right fan as 0, and acting accordingly, when it is in fact working.

What is my best bet to fixing this issue?

I’ve tried an SMC and PRAM reset already.

[image: iStats]

[image: Working, not working]

Thanks,

Comment: Have you run Apple Diagnostics to obtain a hardware report? See: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731 What does it report?

Comment: Yes: PPF004 with additional PPF003 errors.

Comment: Your earlier diagnosis that the problem is controller/sensor hardware looks like it was correct.